# SVG appearing outside of viewport

Tags: html, css, svg

I've tried to make the SVG viewport take up 100% of the width and height of the page here:

http://jsfiddle.net/XZ57u/2/

However it seems to appear only when I change this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100" xml:space="preserve" id="city">
```

To this (viewport size):

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1400 1400" enable-background="new 0 0 1400 1400" xml:space="preserve" id="city">
```

My understanding was that the `100` meant it was taking up the whole viewport percentage so why then does it appear off the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewbox numbers stand for pixels, not for percentatge. If you want to cover the whole container you have to set the SVG elements width and height to 100%

use this instead:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="100%" y="100%" xml:space="preserve" id="city">
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/

Comment: Thank you for the help. The issue is it isn't docked to the bottom like it was before. I was trying to have it so it was aligned to the bottom and extended up. Since they are buildings you can probably imagine how the bottom of the building should start at the bottom of the page. How do I get that alignment back please?

Comment: After looking at this more, it doesn't seem right. The image is falling off the page rather than it being scaled to fit on the page

Comment: I think that's because jsfiddle has some container hidden. I tried it on a personal page and it fits alright. The same happens with copeden: [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovmlu](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ovmlu)

Comment: Thank you. That's the issue though, it isn't showing the buildings at all on my screen, presumably because it is scaling based on the X direction. Is there any way to make sure it always fits the whole height (y direction) of the SVG in? It should really be showing all of the buildings.

Comment: I guess the issue is, I want it to scale to make it as big as possible but still fit within the window and not lose aspect ratio

Comment: I think you should take a look at preserveaspectratio attribute: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio) then

Answer (score 2):

`viewBox="0 0 100 100"`

Simply put `viewbox` defines the coordinate-system limits of your SVG...it has nothing (really) to do with the dimensions of the element in the HTML which you can either set in the SVG itself or in your CSS.

By changing the `viewbox` you are effectively saying, I only want to see the top left 100x100 section of my 1400x1400 SVg.

EDIT: [**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/2/)

with original 1400 viewbox and any CSS dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

you have to define the `viewBox` attribute as well. In addition you could also use `Preserving Aspect Ratio` as well.

```
svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid none">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I already have the percentages in the CSS and adding ```perserveaspectratio``` on the svg doesn't seem to change anything in my fiddle

Comment: sorry initially I didn't see your Fiddle. I've added the SVG circle and its appearing. check the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/XZ57u/4/. Let me know if I catch the exact point.

Comment: Ok, but the SVG circle isn't the example I'm using in the question, so I don't really know if this fixes it or not. It's the cityscape im trying to use

Comment: I would need more time to look at it ..will see your Fiddle then share my thoughts

Comment: I guess the issue is, I want it to scale to make it as big as possible but still fit within the window and not lose aspect ratio

Comment: ```preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"```?